# Unmappable character for encoding UTF-8 Codename One

Tags: java, codenameone

I'm having those issues when I compile my code. I saw a similar question like this, but I don't know where exactly to add `<javac encoding="UTF-8" ... >` in the `build.xml`, if this is really my case. I got to use words with ç á é ã â ô from my brazilian portuguese alphabet.

Comment: Just for the record, the characters "ç á é ã â ô" all exist in ISO-8859-1 encoding as well, so you don't necessarily have to use UTF-8. You just have to make sure the encoding of your source files and the javac encoding setting match.

Comment: @kshetline Thanks I changed everything to ISO-8859-1 it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by opening the build.xml file and changing everything where exists `encoding="UTF-8"` to `encoding="ISO-8859-1"`